# How does spring work when class is not a spring managed bean but an object referred inside is

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a RestTemplate Bean in a spring application like this

```
      @Bean
      public RestTemplate createRT(HttpClient httpClient) {
         return  new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));        
      }
```

Note that HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory isn't a spring managed bean.

HttpClient bean is created as follows:

```
      @Bean
      public CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager, RequestConfig rc) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException { 
          CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
          .create()
          .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)
          .setDefaultRequestConfig(rc)
          .build();
        return httpClient;
      }
```

Note that both PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and RequestConfig are created as spring managed beans.

My question is that in my case, the http client factory object i.e. HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory isn't a spring managed bean but all it's internal objects that it uses to create an HttpClient object for connections are spring managed beans.
So will the HttpClient object that this factory creates going to be a singleton and managed by Spring ? Also would this implementation be considered erroneous in any sense based on the outer object being jvm managed and all inner objects being spring managed ?
I am little confused with it.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem with the given snippet with respect to beans lifecycle. You are right that bean `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` will not be Spring managed, but it would still be singleton, because the it is created inside a bean `RestTemplate` which is singleton. Note that `RestTemplate` bean would be created with name `createRT`.

Now coming to the point if it's considered erroneous: Although this is suggested that you should leave the bean and its dependency to be managed by Spring container. But for simple dependencies like in this case, I have seen developers create bean dependencies this way all the time, and everything works just well.

So, if you can, you should make this as a separate bean and let it come as a dependency for bean `RestTemplate`.